# How to fix the navigation

Tags: react-native

I’m setting up a new service for navigation to "Chat" service but it doesn't do anything and I don't know why.

This is for a new component

here is the "onCancel" button that use the "getCustomerService" function..

```
 handleUnrecognizedUser = () => {
        const infoMsg = {
            onCancel: getCustomerService
        };
    };
```

here is the "getCustomerService" function that get called

```
import { AppStore, RoutingStore } from '../../stores'
import call from 'react-native-phone-call'

callServeiceCenter = (number) => {
    const args = {
        number, // String value with the number to call
        prompt: false // Optional boolean property. Determines if the user should be prompt prior to the call 
    }
    return call(args).catch(console.error)
}

export default getCustomerService = () => {
    if (AppStore.isWorkingHours)
        RoutingStore.goTo('Chat')
    else {
        callServeiceCenter(AppStore.getCallCenterPhone)
    }
}
```

this is for the "RoutingStore" :

```
import { observable, action, computed } from "mobx";
import { NavigationActions, StackActions, DrawerActions } from 'react-navigation'

class RoutingStore {
    @observable nav = null;
    @observable PrevPage = null;
    @observable curentPage = null;
    @observable isGoBackAvailable = true;
    @observable isLoggedIn = false;

    @action
    setNavigation(data) {
        this.nav = data
    }

    goTo = (data, _params) => {
        let { routeName, params } = data
        const navigateAction = NavigationActions.navigate(
            routeName
                ? { routeName, params }
                : { routeName: data, params: { ..._params } })

        this.nav.dispatch(navigateAction)
    }

    @action
    goBack = () => {
    }

    @action
    updateCurrentPage(data) {
        this.curentPage = data
    }

    @action
    updatePrevPage(data) {
        this.PrevPage = data
    }

    updatePages = (prev, cur) => {
        this.updatePrevPage(prev)
        this.updateCurrentPage(cur)
    }

    @action
    setLoggedIn(status) {
        this.isLoggedIn = status
    }

    @action
    openDrawer() {
        this.nav.dispatch(DrawerActions.openDrawer())
    }

    @action
    closeDrawer() {
        this.nav.dispatch(DrawerActions.closeDrawer())
    }

    @action
    toggleDrawer() {
        this.nav.dispatch(DrawerActions.toggleDrawer())
    }

    disableLoginRoute = (route) => {
        const resetAction = StackActions.reset({
            index: 0,
            key: null,
            actions: [NavigationActions.navigate({ routeName: route })],
        });
        this.nav.dispatch(resetAction)
    }

    isGoBackAllowed = () => {
        switch (this.curentPage) {
            case "Tabs": return false
            case "Login": return false
            default: return this.goBack()
        }
    }

    @computed
    get isNonLogin() {
        return this.isLoggedIn;
    }

    @computed
    get getCurentPage() {
        return this.curentPage;
    }

}

const routingStore = new RoutingStore();
export default routingStore;
```

I expect to navigate to the Chat as well.

Comment: I guess you need to share the code from `AppStore` and `RoutingStore` as well because from the code snippet above it's not very clear what they do and what `showAlert` does with the `infoMsg` object.

Comment: i add the "RoutingStore" as u ask for .
i removed the "this.props.AppStore.showAlert(infoMsg)"..

Comment: What's the log output of `this.nav` when `goTo` gets called?

Comment: he get called when i go to onCance and then its call to  ===>  "getCustomerService"

Comment: Have you tried adding some console.log statements to see if this call actually happens and what `this.nav` actually contains? My assumption is that it's not properly set at the moment of execution.